# cannot request to backend (node.js) blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

im hosting my react app on cpanel
with the directory tree look like this

```
public_html
|- 2nd react app
   |- .htaccess
   |- all the builded react file
|- backend (node js)
   |- .htaccess
   |- index.js
   |- all the node js file
|- all the builded react file
|- .htaccess
```

so i've tested it using postman when i'm running my backend on local it works just fine, but when i post it on the cpanel it says this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myweb.com/auth/login' from origin 'https://myweb.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i've add the cors in the index.js (node) as said in some references

here's my code :

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const { sequelize } = require('./utils/db');
const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://myweb.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.JWT_KEY));

app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/products',authMiddleware, require('./routes/product'));

sequelize.sync()
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('Server started on port 3000');
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

but it still giving me the same error.

and i also tried to add some config to the htaccess in the backend directory :

```apache
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/project/public_html/api.myweb.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/project/nodevenv/public_html/api.myweb.com/18/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile index.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^https?://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?(myweb\.com)$" CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN}e env=CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

and for note i've try to add the mod_header into the htaccess on the root and my 2nd react app.

but all of that still giving me the exact same error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.myweb.com/auth/login' from origin 'https://myweb.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i'm totally clueless, and would really appreciate your help.

**EDIT**

this is the additional htaccess on the main root and the 2nd react app

**main root**

```apache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**2nd react app**

```apache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /otherapp/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /otherapp/index.html [L]
  </IfModule>
```

and some little information, the other app is the one that will do all the request into the backend.

Comment: Why are you using both the `cors()` middleware (good) with your own custom CORS middleware (bad)?

Comment: just trying stuff to make it works, i will remove the custom one later

Comment: I'd remove it now since it clearly conflicts with your `corsOptions`

Comment: unfortunately it still giving me the same error after i remove it, ill update the code on the post

Comment: Since the middleware is handling CORS, you shouldn't need the Apache config though I can't really see that being the problem, just trying to eliminate possibilities

Comment: i'm not quite familiar with apache config, the one i wrote on the post is auto generated, i was wondering if the htaccess block the access into my backend, i'll add some details for the other two htaccess